# Engagement split journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey where around 1100 entries entered the journey. They all received the first email and then I added an engagement split. If people opened the first email they follow the 'yes' path, if they did not' they follow the 'no' path. I see 611 unique opens, so people should go the both of the paths. However, I do not see them following the path and for exmaple not getting the second email down the 'no' path.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Regards, 
Els

[image: overview]
[image: Unique opens]

Comment: Has it been a week since you started the journey? Those people look like they're just stuck in the wait period at the moment. Once a week is passed, if you've done everything right they should go down the right path.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help. No the journey already started on 28th of August and the automation is running daily till 2021, so they are already a longer period then a week in the wait period. Do you have any other idea? 

Regards, 
Els

Comment: Hi Els, can you check your journey's history just to confirm that the second email has been sent to contacts or not. I have had instances where the number is not displayed on the journey emails even if contacts are receiving emails. Or you can just create a journey tracking report to check this.

Comment: It may be erroring out, are you using ampscript in the email? If so can you post that?

Comment: Thank @KratiGarg, I checked the journey's history but people did not received the second email. No distinction when people opened or clicked in the email and the exit criteria are not either.

Comment: @garek007, Yes I do think that we are using ampscript but I am quite new to that. How can I post the ampscript, where can I find it? We use at least a personalisation token %%Firstname%%, but maybe there is more.

Comment: Look in the HTML for anything with %%, you can do a search. If you can't post the code, then at least make sure that your personalization strings match columns in the Data Extension which you are sending to.

Comment: Seems they are stuck at the wait step, log a support case to get details as to why

Comment: @garek007, I have added an image with the HTML and %% highlighted. Would be great if you can take a look, I do not see anything strange in here. Otherwise I will log a support case to let them check. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @garek007 I see that I can't add an iamge, and the code is too long to add it here. I think the easiest way is to log a support case right?

Comment: I suppose if we can't help you then support is your only option

Comment: thanks for your anyway @garek007!

Answer (score 0):

You could be missing the open pixel in the email: `<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">`

Does it show opens in the tracking info?